# Three Update ConvexGeometry dynamically

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm using THREE.js in Aframe and attempting to build a mesh by clicking points.

This is working, however the I'm struggling to update the Geometry to show the changes.

```
this._shapeEl = make('a-entity', {
  material: {color: 'blue'},
  geometry: this._vertices.length > 3 ? new THREE.ConvexGeometry( this._vertices ) : new THREE.Geometry(),
}, this.el)
```

onClick:

```
var target = e.detail.intersection.point
this.el.object3D.worldToLocal(target)

make('a-sphere', {
  color: darkViolet,
  radius: 0.01,
  position: target,
}, this.el)

this._vertices.push(target)

if(this._vertices.length > 3){
  this._shapeEl.object3D.geometry = new THREE.ConvexGeometry( this._vertices )
  this._shapeEl.object3D.geometry.dynamic = true
}
```

The spheres show, and the points are getting added but the _shapeEl isn;t changing from a blue cube.

Comment: Some tips: If you replace the geometry like so, you should call `dispose()` on the old geometry: `this._shapeEl.object3D.geometry.dispose()`. Then you can assign a new instance of `THREE.ConvexGeometry`. Besides, setting the `dynamic` flag to `true` does not make sense since it belongs to `THREE.BufferAttribute`, not `THREE.Geometry`. You want to set this flag if you frequently (e.g. per frame) update the contents of a buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mugen87 that was useful.

The answer is to use the object3Dmap.mesh

```
  this._shapeEl.object3DMap.mesh.geometry.dispose()
  this._shapeEl.object3DMap.mesh.geometry = new THREE.ConvexGeometry( this._vertices )
```